# Rails: select related active records on join table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two models `Magazine.rb` and `Keyword.rb`, both are related through a simple join table. One magazine is defined by many keywords and a keyword can define many magazines.

```
class Keyword < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :word
  has_and_belongs_to_many :magazines, :join_table => "magazines_keywords"
end

class Magazine < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :keywords, :join_table => "magazines_keywords" 
end
```

Now I would like to display on the `ingredients/show.html.erb` all the keywords that are related to a given keyword through a magazine or several magazines, which would be all the other keywords which share the same magazine_id on the join table. My controller action is the following:

```
class IngredientsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @keyword = Keyword.find(params[:id])
    @keywords = Keyword.find(:all, :order => 'word ASC')
    @k = Keyword.count
  end
```

I have currently in my view:

```
Related Keywords
<% i= @k
for keyword in @keywords %>
  <a href="/ingredients/<%= keyword.id %>">
    <div class="keyword">
      <%= keyword.word %>
    </div>
  </a>
<%  i -= 1
end %>
```

But I get displayed all the keywords. How can I achieve to get only the related entries?

Update

On the same view I am able to display all the magazines related to a given keyword through:

```
Related Magazines
<% @keyword.magazines.each do |s| %>
  <div>
    <a href='/magazines/<%= s.id %>')>
      <div>Magazin <%= s.number %></div>
    </a>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I am little confused! Is your goal to relate keywords with keywords or keywords with magazines?

Comment: @dstrants In this case I would like to relate keywords to keywords through magazines. On the same page I am able to display all the related magazines through `@keyword.safts.each do`.

Comment: Did you try to use the magazine you find with `@keyword.safts`  to find the keywords you are searching? I mean, just do the opposite thing after locating the magazine.

Comment: @dstrants I see. But how would I accomplish this?

Comment: I think you can do it the same way. Assuming `@magazine` is one of the magazines you found through `@keyword.safts` you can do this `@magazine.keywords` to get a list of the keywords related to the `@magazine`.

Comment: @dstrants It works, when i wrap a `<% s.keywords.each do |kw| %>` inside a `<% @keyword.safts.each do |s| %>`! But obviously I get the results not in alphabetical order, but divided per magazine and then in alphabetical order. But this could be one possible solution! Thank you! I think in order to get all related keywords in alphabetical order the solution is in the controller action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get only related keywords, try to use below query:

```
@keywords = Keyword.joins(magazines: :keywords).where('keywords_magazines_join.keyword_id': @keyword.id).uniq.order(:word)
```

`keywords_magazines_join` is a alias generated by Rails for magazines_keywords table after the first `INNER JOIN` of this table.

Comment: Thank you for your input. When using your first proposal with `.where('keywords.id' => @keyword.id)` the view loads the correct number of keyword entries, but displays the same keyword! Your updated proposal `.where('magazines_keywords_magazines_join.id': @keyword.id)` throws `Mysql::Error: Unknown column 'magazines_keywords_magazines_join.id' in 'where clause'`.

Comment: Can you run `Keyword.joins(magazines: :keywords)` in rails console and provide the query is generated by Rails.

Comment: I get `Keyword.joins(:safts => :keywords)
  Keyword Load (57.5ms)  SELECT 'keywords'.* FROM 'keywords' INNER JOIN 'magazines_keywords' ON 'magazines_keywords '.'keyword_id' = 'keywords'.'id' INNER JOIN 'magazines' ON 'magazines'.'id' = 'magazines_keywords'.'saft_id' INNER JOIN 'magazines_keywords ' 'keywords_magazines_join' ON 'keywords_magazines_join'.'magazin_id' = 'magazines'.'id' INNER JOIN 'keywords' 'keywords_magazines' ON 'keywords_magazines'.'id' = 'keywords_magazines_join'.'keyword_id'` Quite a sentence ;0)

Comment: Something strange happens with `.where('keywords_magazines_join.id': @keyword.id)`. When I implement it I get 23 data entries instead of the 18 I should get.

Comment: Your input takes the keyword.id from the keyword table and checks it as the association.id on the join table. Then i get all the keyword entries in the resulting dataset.

Comment: @SEJU: My bad. It should be `keywords_magazines_join.keyword_id` in the where clause instead of `keywords_magazines_join.id`.